Failed to link C++ programm
I have task.h file with this class:
enum MENULAYOUT { LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, CENTER, CUSTOM };

template<MENULAYOUT lay>
class Menu: public Drawable {
  public:

    Menu(int O)
        requires(lay != CENTER && lay != CUSTOM);

    Menu(int upDownOffset, int leftRightOffset)
        requires(lay == CENTER);

    Menu(int X, int Y, int W, int H)
        requires(lay == CUSTOM);
    
    ....
};

And task.cpp file with definitions:
template<MENULAYOUT lay>
Menu<lay>::Menu(int O)
    requires(lay != CENTER && lay != CUSTOM)
{
    ....
}

template<MENULAYOUT lay>
Menu<lay>::Menu(int upDownOffset, int leftRightOffset)
    requires(lay == CENTER)
{
    ....
}

template<MENULAYOUT lay>
Menu<lay>::Menu(int X, int Y, int W, int H)
    requires(lay == CUSTOM)
{
    ....
}


And using this stuff in main.cpp
#include "task.h"

int main() {
    ....

    Menu<RIGHT> mainMenu(10);
    
    ....
}


CmakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

project(tracker)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} "src/*.cpp")

add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCES})

include(FindPkgConfig)

pkg_search_module(SDL2 REQUIRED sdl2)
pkg_search_module(SDL2TTF REQUIRED SDL2_ttf>=2.0.0)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SDL2TTF_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES} ${SDL2TTF_LIBRARIES})

tree of my project:
CMakeLists.txt
src/
    main.cpp
    task.cpp
    task.h
build/
    ....


When trying to build got this error:
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/home/sigaretov/src/tracker/src/main.cpp:33:(.text+0x1dd): undefined reference to `Menu<(MENULAYOUT)1>::Menu(int)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/src/main.cpp.o:(.data.rel.ro._ZTV4MenuIL10MENULAYOUT1EE[_ZTV4MenuIL10MENULAYOUT1EE]+0x10): undefined reference to `Menu<(MENULAYOUT)1>::draw()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/build.make:129: tracker] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/tracker.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

I tried to move definitions to task.h and it works perfectly, but I can't understand what is wrong with definitions in separate file.
